# Authentication / login issue on cross applications on same web server | IIS 7.5 install

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms

There are two applications setup on the same server, GamesPlayLogin & GamesPlay. [ Windows server 2008 R2 ]

So, once the users are authenticated using the Login application ( GamesPlayLogin),

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="GamesLoginCheck" loginUrl="/GamesPlayLogin/Default.aspx"  
         timeout="240" path="/" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

They are redirected to the application : GamesPlay. but on doing redirect, Authentication is failing every time and users are getting redirected back to first application: GamesPlayLogin.

As per the requirements decision, The two applications are setup to run in different application pools, possibly to avoid problems occurring in one of the apps affecting the other. And we are using Autogenerated keys.

Also, we made sure that the  the box for “Generate a unique key for each application” is unchecked by checking the IIS ( Version 7.5).

event log shows::

```
Event message: Forms authentication failed for the request
Reason: The ticket supplied was invalid
```

I got to see many solutions related to above event log but NO success. Firstly My applications are on  SAME WEB SERVER, and also the same setup using Autogenerated key was working earlier ( Windows server 2008 ,, until we recently did a migration to windows server 2008 R2).

I'm still looking for reasons why the same setup worked earlier ( Windows server 2008) but not after moving to Windows 2008 R2 recently.

Comment: I think this is what you need. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx Here's a bit more on generating the keys. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=155113 Make sure the settings are the same across the two applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a difference between IIS 7 & 7.5 that default identity of the application pool was changed from Network Service to an automatically generated AppPool identity.

Also,  the two application pools were running under different users.

Since, the autogenkey are stored on a per user basis,, and the two processes are running under different users they will have different autogen keys, which finally explains why we are seeing issues here.

Going through ***[the DEV'S Blog](http://blogs.iis.net/davcox/archive/2009/08/12/what-is-my-iis-code-running-as.aspx)***, finally proved a lot helpful.

Finally, taking into account our requirements, we changed the identity of the application pool to the same user for each app pools.

Also,[this blog post](http://blog.zygonia.net/2006/10/26/ASPNET20AspnetregiisGaSwitch.aspx) by Kev describes how are autogenkey stored in the registry.